# Using a series to approximate an inverse.

Tags: sequences-and-series, laplace-transform, functional-equations

Hi I was looking at a quick way to remember converting farenheit to centigrade. It's easy to remember subtract or add 32 but then you have to multiply or divide by 1.8. I approximated this to 2. On looking at the error I saw if I added the multiplication  or division  by .2 it was very close to the correct answer. So I started playing with approximations of 1/(a+b). I got 1/a - b/(a^2+ab). If you do the same approximation on the last term a series starts to appear. I remember vaguely from school that was a polynomial series. I Googled Lagrange and a few others but could not find it.

Does anyone remember the approximation of 1/(x+a) as 1/x + b/x^n .....

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. There is a series expansion: $\dfrac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+...$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The approximation of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x+a}=\frac{\frac{1}{a}}{1-(-\frac{x}{a})}=\frac{1}{a}\left(1-\frac{x}{a}+\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^3}{a^3}...
\right)$

Comment: best for small values of x

Comment: Thanks. Does it have a name? I remember it vaguely ftom school or university.

Comment: taylor series @Gary

Comment: Thanks. I guess x/a has to be less than one. The proof error approaches zero as n approaches infinity. 1 = 1 +- (x/a)^n